# Нужно воспроизвести цепочку диалогов из таблицы

Tags: python, table

есть такая [таблица](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p069J4GJEC6ToUugihAJRr8UBmuvl_OS?usp=sharing):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Первый столбец (First Message) содержит текст сообщения;
- Второй столбец (First Person) содержит идентификатор того, кто отправил
  это сообщение;
- Третий столбец (Second Message) содержит ответ на
  Первое сообщение;
- Четвертая колонка (Second Person) содержит
  идентификатор отправителя.

Не могу понять, как пройти всю таблицу и восстановить цепочку диалогов. Если диалог продолжается, то сообщение в столбце "Second Message" будет в столбце "First Message"

Мне нужно чтобы на выводе было что-то вроде такого:
[
[
'wow new channel again!',
'pretty cool right ?',
'yeah 2 in a row man',
'oh yea im not sure if anyone here is actually Mongolian'
],
['where is mongolia?'],
['hi bro']
]

То есть список диалогов.

Ссылка на таблицу:

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не получается сообразить как именно цикл обхода написать

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не заморачивался с циклами, а попробовал решить все с помощью pandas и numpy.

Предположим, вы сохранили свою таблицу в csv-файл `messages.csv`. Тогда:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("messages.csv")
dfmsgs = df[["First Person", "Second Person"]]
a = dfmsgs.values
a.sort(axis=1)
dfmsgs = dfmsgs.assign(chains = tuple(a.tolist()))

for i, g in dfmsgs.groupby("chains")["First Person"]:
    idx = g.index.tolist()
    print("===start===")
    print(df.loc[idx, "First Message"].values.tolist())
    print("====end====")
```

на выходе получаем такое:

```
===start===
['I have another friend, his name is Max, he has problems with his head', 'idi na*** urod', 'not you, another Max']
====end====
===start===
['heloo hello']
====end====
===start===
['yah this chat is so much calmer', 'agreed mate!!!!!!', 'finally hit lvl 7 guys!', 'Legend', 'how much longer do you have to 7?', 'Half way through level 2 rn! Plan to be on it all night', 'goodluck friend']
====end====
===start===
['oh woah this channel exist']
====end====
===start===
["honestly mate NFTS as a whole are so life changing and we need more people to know that....  that's why its great with these types of project where they are linking the fashion world with NFTS are amazing", 'agreed! and this year will be massive for those of us in the space so early ', 'oh yes people do not know wat they are missing with NFTS and it will hit them!', 'anyonme know when they will be updating the WL?']
====end====

и т.д.
```